# How to create relational tables from a flat table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this input table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` ( 
   `id` INTEGER, 
   `a`  INTEGER, 
   `b` INTEGER, 
   `c` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`) )
```

With this data:

```
id a b c
-- - - -
 1 1 4 a
 2 1 5 a
 3 1 6 b
 4 2 4 a
 5 1 5 c
```

As I have many other columns `b`, `c`, ... on this table and a lot of redundancy. For example, we see that entry `1` is the same as entry `4` so I would like to create relational tables from this flat table and eventually drop `data` in favor of my two new tables and create a `view` named `data`

The goal is to create two tables `bc` and `a` with the following:

```
a                  bc
--------           --
id id_bc           id b c
-- -----           -- - -
 1 1               1  4 a
 2 2               2  5 a
 3 3               3  6 b
 4 1               4  4 c
 5 4
```

Getting `bc` is easy with:

```
CREATE TABLE bc AS SELECT DISTINCT b,c FROM data
```

But I don't know how:

1. Create `bc` with an `id` column
2. Create `a` with foreign relation to `bc`

Comment: Check the usage of `distinct`. If you enter `select distinct b,c` you will get the list of all possible combinations between b and c without repetitions. Once you have this, you can create the first table (i.e. for id and id_bc).

Comment: I am using `distinct` as you can see above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the creation of table `bc`, then do so, instead of using `create table ... as select`. (Or, refer to the row identifier as `rowid` instead of giving it a custom name.)

```
create table bc(
    id integer primary key,
    b integer,
    c integer)

insert into bc(b,c) select distinct b,c from data
```

For `a`, since you want a foreign key, you cannot use `create table ... as select`.

```
create table a(
    id integer primary key,
    id_bc integer,
    foreign key (id_bc) references bc(id))

insert into a(id_bc)
select bc.id from data inner join bc
  on data.b = bc.b and data.c = bc.c
```

Omitting the primary key in each insert statement (or specifying null) will use autoincrement.

Comment: Would it be possible to simplify the test of any column in the latter part?

Comment: Are you sure you don't forget `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE` for the `bc` table? It didn't autoincrement anything here

Comment: I'm not sure what could be different. Here's the python script I was using to test this https://gist.github.com/jleedev/7b2fa91103e4bab961b363bf679c4f41